# Changing HTML menubar based on php session properties?

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement

So, I have a MySQL database that list users as managers or employees.  I want to change the menubar that they see based on the properties.  I did have all this done in php, but when going through a re-design I thought about putting it in html files, but I can't quite figure out how this should work.

Here is the php code that I was using to do the operation in the file menubar2.php:

```
<?php
$email = $_SESSION['logname'];
$results = "SELECT email FROM manager_list WHERE email = '$email'";
$results = mysqli_query($cxn, $results) or die("Query died: query");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($results);

if ($numrows == 0)
{
    echo"<div id='menu'>";
    echo"<ul>";
    echo"<li><a href='index2.php'>Quick Review</a></li>";
    echo"<li><a href='myPerformance.php'>My Peformance</a></li>";
    echo"<li><a href='myGoals.php'>My Goals</a></li>";
    echo"<li><a href='sHelp.php'>Help</a></li>";
    echo"</ul>";
    echo"</div>";
}

if ($numrows > 0)
{
    echo"<div id='menu'>";
    echo"<ul>";
    echo"<li><a href='index2.php'>Quick Review</a></li>";
    echo"<li><a href='myPerformance.php'>My Peformance</a></li>";
    echo"<li><a href='myGoals.php'>My Goals</a></li>";
    echo"<li><a href='toolsManager.php'>Manager Tools</a></li>";
    echo"<li><a href='sHelp.php'>Help</a></li>";
    echo"</ul>";
    echo"</div>";
}
?>
```

And here is where I was using it (index.html)

```
<?php
include('sessionauth.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>TinyEval</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<?php 
include('header2.php');
include('menubar2.php'); 
?>
    <!-- begin #page -->
    <div id="page">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="post">
                <h2 class="title">Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
                <div class="entry">

                    <p>How do I fix my headers?</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
    <!-- end #page -->
</div>
<?php include('footer2.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way I can do this without the `include` for the menubar2.php - that is, put it all in the html file itself, but without having to use all the `echo` statements?

Sorry for the newb question, but I'm driving myself batty trying to figure out how html and php/MySQL all tie together.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes sure you can, but I think it wise to keep it in separate files, in case you need that menu on another page, then you won't have to copy and paste that code in the second file, rather include the menu file overthere.

Comment: In order for PHP to work, even if you're just including php, the file has to be named index.php, not index.html

Comment: You need MVC, please read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller I would suggest to checkout a framework to do what you need in nice code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is solid, so long as you name your index file index.php. PHP was originally an HTML templating language, and using it like this with includes for portions of the page is perfectly correct. You could put that code directly into index.php, but using includes makes your code more reusable. Also, here is simpler and more DRY way to alter the menu when you get more than 0 rows back:

```
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($results);

//these lines get echoed in both cases
echo "<div id='menu'>";
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li><a href='index2.php'>Quick Review</a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='myPerformance.php'>My Peformance</a></li>";
echo "<li><a href='myGoals.php'>My Goals</a></li>";
if ($numrows > 0) {
    echo "<li><a href='toolsManager.php'>Manager Tools</a></li>";
}
echo "<li><a href='sHelp.php'>Help</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
```

To expand just a bit further on PHP - it's a server-side language, meaning it does not run in the user's browser like Javascript. When the browser requests a page that ends in PHP, the server runs the script, prints out the results (usually as HTML) and gives the browser only *the rendered output*. In this case, even though your main index.php and the includes all have php scripts in them,  what appears in the browser is the output of the script only.